# Excel export all the text content

Tags: excel, postgresql

I need your help. Because currently I have a project which is a database of all the information of our client, all those information are stored in excel so we have a thousand of excel(30-40 sheets per excel file) information from the customers. the problem is how can I extract all the information from the excel? so that I can stored it in the database using import templates on postgresql. right now im doing manual but I end up 10 excel import per day. I already created the front end. I am tired of doing it manually and I don't know if I can finish it on the given date. Many thanks

Comment: Try Geokettle, Its an Open Source ETL tool.

Comment: What’s the reason for needing to store it in a relational database?